# Map is not visible after update

Tags: android, google-maps

Yesterday i updated my application, this is the 7th update till 6th version the map is visible  but from today i am getting this issue. I created the map API key in release mode also. I am using v1 of map api
Any idea . Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably good to raise it with google.

Comment: have you got rid of it,/???? #user2046620,
I did the same update , and map not visible,